# Can upload Django media, can't retrieve

Tags: python, django

As the title states, I am lost here because I can upload files to MEDIA_ROOT via the site, but when I attempt to serve them I get a 404 error. The most annoying part is that this worked for ages, now something changed and it's broken.

## UPDATE: I've narrowed the problem down.

If I change:
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

Django serves the file at `http://192.168.xxx.xxx/media/media/file.txt`

If I change:
`MEDIA_URL = '/kittens/'`

Django serves the file at `http://192.168.xxx.xxx/kittens/file.txt`

runserver output:

```
urls.py MEDIA_URL: /media/
urls.py MEDIA_ROOT:
Settings.py MEDIA_ROOT: /home/user/kittens/
```

What in the world is going on? Why the "nested" media url path? `django.conf.settings.MEDIA_ROOT` is blank while `mysite.settings.MEDIA_ROOT` is not?

## urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

print 'urls.py MEDIA_URL: %s' % (settings.MEDIA_URL)
print 'urls.py MEDIA_ROOT: %s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/kittens/'

print 'Settings.py MEDIA_ROOT: %s' % (MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## On the disk

```
drwxr-xr-x 0 user user     0 Mar 11 11:00 kittens/
-rwxr-xr-x 0 user user 22561 Oct  5 19:17 kittens/file.txt*
```

## In the browser

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.../media/file.txt

"file.txt" does not exist
```

## python manage.py runserver

```
[11/Mar/2014 15:00:43] "GET /media/file.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 1629
```

## python manage.py shell

```
IPython 1.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: settings.MEDIA_ROOT
Out[2]: 'kittens/'

In [3]: settings.MEDIA_URL
Out[3]: '/media/'

In [8]: os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'file.txt')
Out[8]: 'kittens/file.txt'

In [9]: os.path.exists(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'file.txt'))
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: Why is file.txt executable? Did you try after removing that attribute?

Comment: It's a mounted NTFS share so the perms are stuck like that. BUT, that's not the issue, 1) That has been the config since the beginning (when it worked), 2) To verify I moved the media path to the local filesystem with perms `rw` and it still fails to serve the file.

Comment: [`MEDIA_ROOT` is expected to be absolute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#media-root)

Comment: `MEDIA_ROOT` is absolute on my box. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was isolated by printing the configuration parameters, i.e.:

## settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/kittens/'

print 'Settings.py MEDIA_ROOT: %s' % (MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

print 'urls.py MEDIA_URL: %s' % (settings.MEDIA_URL)
print 'urls.py MEDIA_ROOT: %s' % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

## python manage.py runserver

```
urls.py MEDIA_URL: /media/
urls.py MEDIA_ROOT:
Settings.py MEDIA_ROOT: /home/user/kittens
Validating models...
```

You'll notice the `urls.py` `MEDIA_ROOT` is blank. After inspecting `settings.py` I noticed that the root url configuration was being called before `MEDIA_ROOT` was configured. Therefore, changing the order fixed the problem.

## settings.py

```
# Must specify MEDIA_ROOT first so urls.py picks it up via django.conf.settings
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/kittens'
# Then call site root's urls.py
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

I don't know *how* this caused the "nested" media path, but the change did fix it regardless. That is, I can navigate to `http://192.168.xxx.xxx/media/file.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

As per django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#media-root), MEDIA_ROOT ***must*** be absolute path:

> MEDIA_ROOT
>
> Default: '' (Empty string)
>
> **Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded
>   files.**
>
> Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"

So your configuration should be something like this if you want media to be inside your project:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'kittens/')
```

or an absolute path:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = /user/uploaded/files/kittens/
```

**Edit:**
Since you updated your question above answer is not relevant. But I can see problem with your url config where you configure the media path twice:

```
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

the second line should be enough..

Comment: Hi, `stackoverflow` is behaving badly today, perhaps you didn't see my update. On my machine the path is absolute. However, I have narrowed down the problem, but I still need help. See the update above.

Comment: @TechMedicNYC oh, now you edited your question. you are changing and debugging your code here in stackoverflow, we cannot help if you keep changing the code. we just can't

Comment: @TechMedicNYC both changes you made makes a big difference, you cant tell me that MEDIA_ROOT = 'kittens/' and then it becomes MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/user/kittens/'

Comment: @TechMedicNYC why do you put wrong code in your question, why not put the actual config and code?

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but I don't feel comfortable cutting and pasting what could be proprietary code for public view. Thus I tried to simplify the problem. I think this may be frustrating you not because I did that, but because I'm root-causing this thing as I dive into it. Again, I'm not trying to be difficult. Originally I thought it might be a permissions issue. Then I discovered that some how the served path was nested. But when you change the url it's no longer nested. I added a few more print statements to try and debug. I don't know why it's behaving this way.

Comment: P.s., originally on my machine it was relative path, aka `MEDIA_ROOT='kittens/'`, but again, to troubleshoot I changed it to absolute path, which per the docs is the right way to do it anyway. But that is how and why that line of code changed. In any event, that was not the actual root cause of the issue, that is it worked either way!