# Django can upload files to /media/ but gives 404 in production

Tags: python, django, apache

I just looked at others threads such as [Can upload Django media, can't retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22329686/can-upload-django-media-cant-retrieve) but I did not find the answer to my question. I also followed https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ without any success...

I just passed my website from development to production and since then, every uploaded files is providing a 404 mistakes when I try to access it from webpages. The strange thing is that they are all in the /media/ folders on the servers, therefore I am able to upload them without trouble.

What is wrong in my configuration ?

**settings.py**

```
# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) 

# Media Files (Uploaded pictures, etc)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'upload')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
...    
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf**

```
Alias /media/ /var/www/SIS/media/
<Directory /var/www/SIS/media/>
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

It only affect the /media/ folders, all static files are served well.

Many thanks !

Comment: If you have `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'upload')`, then the media will be saved in `/var/www/SIS/upload/`, not `/var/www/SIS/media/` as you have in your Apache config.

Comment: You don't need this line in production:

`+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

The web server (apache in your case) should be serving the media urls without Django.

Comment: Many thanks, it is working now !

Comment: @Crow you saved my day.... removing that line in production did the trick... I also had to set the proper `/media` alias in my apache config files